# angular material select in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-material

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in gridData">
        <td>
            {{row.bank_ac_no}}
                <md-select placeholder="select AC" ng-model="row.bank_ac_no" md-on-open="loadUsers()">
                    <md-option ng-value="user" ng-repeat="user in users">{{user.bankacno}}</md-option>
                </md-select>                
        </td>

        <td>
            <div>
                <button ng-click="saveData(row)"></button>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This is my html, clearly, I am adding mdSelect within a loop, so I have to use the same ng-model for all of them in the loop, I want the "row.bank_ac_no" to store the name of md-select selected of the particular row. I am getting the whole json object in the ng-model instead of just the name in it. What should be done? Thanks in advance. :)

please refer to my pen [here](http://codepen.io/VallabhRao/pen/YWdmVg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want? When I select a user, now I just get the name and not the whole json. [Check my fork](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/akPZLK) of your pen

All I had to do was set the `ng-value` to `user.bankacno`.

```
<md-option ng-value="user.bankacno" ng-repeat="user in users">
 {{user.bankacno}
</md-option>
```

Comment: You are welcome! If you think I answered your question, please mark the answer as accepted!